# ClickHouse MYSQL driver for Windows is not working

Tags: mysql, clickhouse

The **MYSQL** command line client that is installed on the **ClickHouse** CENTOS server works fine. My windows driver accessing CH from a remote Windows server can connect (when using the ODBC administrator)but does not work when using the connector from an application.  I also tested a **MYSQL** driver from a remote linux application, it would not work either. I have tried a few MYSQL drivers from version 5-8 and from Oracle and MariaDB. I am getting errors from the MYSQL driver, I cannot resolve

One of the errors:

```
Details: "ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-20.4.2.9-ClickHouse]Syntax error: failed at position 5: @@sql_select_limit=DEFAULT. Expected one of: ROLE, identifier, ROLE DEFAULT, DEFAULT ROLE"
```

A second error (different client):

```
could not load system variables
Syntax error: failed at position 6: VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name in ('max_allowed_packet','system_time_zone','time_zone','auto_increment_increment'). Expected one of: TABLES, GRANTS, CREATE, QUOTA USAGE, POLICIES, ROW POLICIES, PROCESSLIST, CREATE, QUOTAS, DICTIONARIES
```

It is important that I get the **MYSQL** interface working. Any ideas?

Comment: CH Mysql protocol does not implement all variables. You should open an issue https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse

Answer (score 0):

You try to use MySQL ODBC driver to connect to Clickhouse via ODBC via MySQL wire protocol
Clickhouse implements only the wired MySQL protocol but does not implement the entire SQL dialect of MySQL.

It looks like ODBC drivers that you try to use make additional SQL queries after successfully connecting to MySQL,

Can you change the Connector from ODBC to the native MySQL protocol?
What language do you use?

Comment: I am seeing that the tools I am using are making additional call after the connection.  I tried DBeaver and it can connect using MariaDB drivers though it does fail when trying to drill down into the tables or describe a table. It looks like any DDL type of call is not supported functionality. All I can do is run 'select' statements.... the MYSQL supports is not useful for BI connectivity unless I am doing something wrong here... I think all tools (Excel, PowerBI etc..) want to see the table DDL. I was hoping there was a way to configure MYSQL driver to avoid the errors.

Comment: The other thing I tried is the ODBC driver using the ODBC administrator. I cannot get that to work at all and the interface does not provide a 'test' button. I also see that every time I go back into the ODBC configuration, the default settings are shown so I am not sure if it is actually saving my CH server settings. I am surprised to trip on these simple things, hopefully I am making a simple mistake here...

Comment: @user13607078 DBeaver can use official Clickhouse JDBC connector

I can't understand what is your use case? 

Why you try to use Clickhouse as MySQL server with MySQL dialect?

If you try use clickhouse from PowerBI or Excel - please try to use official clickhouse ODBC driver https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-odbc/